# Possible to reduce lookahead on potentially ambiguous expressions

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, grammar, compiler-optimization

This is somewhat related to my previous question [Ambiguity between tuple and parenthesized expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73450324/ambiguity-between-tuple-and-parenthesized-expression), but now about if there is a way to improve the number of lookaheads needed to resolve what type of expression something is.

In the following grammar, a tuple is differentiated between a parenthesized expression by whether it has a comma or not.

```
grammar DBParser;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }
statement: select EOF;

select:
    'SELECT' expr (',' expr)*
    ('FROM' expr) ?
    ('WHERE' expr) ?
    ;

expr
    : '(' expr ')'              # parenExpression
    | '(' expr (',' expr)+ ')'  # tupleLiteralExpression
    | expr 'IN' expr            # inExpression
    | '(' select ')'            # subSelectExpression
    | Atom                      # constantExpression
    ;

Atom:
    [a-z-]+ | [0-9]+ | '\'' Atom '\''
    ;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Because the first expression may be quite complex, and we don't know whether it will resolve to a tuple or not until after evaluating the first expression, we potentially need a very large lookahead to resolve this -- in the following we need 52 tokens -- in other words, the sub-select expression 'needs to finish' before it can make the determination on what expression type it is.

[image]

Related to this I have a few questions:

1. Is a very large lookahead number always a bad thing?
2. Does a larger K value (more lookaheads) always imply a slower parse?
3. If it is, are there any ways to resolve it. Or it's more an "it's just what it is".

Comment: How do you represent a tuple with one element?

Comment: @rici I guess you don't (in BigQuery's case), or I suppose a trailing comma might work too (such as in python).

Comment: Apparently, you need to use the `STRUCT` keyword to create a one-element tuple. ("To write a struct literal with a single field, use typeless struct syntax or typed struct syntax.") Allowing trailing commas would have been less wordy, but "less wordy" is not a goal for SQL.

Comment: Anyway, is there a good reason why you need to tag parenthesized expressions and tuple literals with different tags? Because you could just replace both of those productions; `expr: '(' expr (',' expr)* ')' `. Once you've got the parenthesized object, you only need to look at the number of elements that were produced to distinguish the two cases.

Comment: This whole thing of recognising productions in advance is an artefact of LL() parsing. It's not inherent in context-free grammars. The grammar is not "potentially ambiguous"; it's just not LL(k). But commonly, as in this case, it's not necessary to know which production will match before the end of the production. An LR parser, which reduces at the end of a production instead of trying to predict at the beginning, will not require additional lookahead. By careful left-factoring you could write an LL(1) grammar, as well (in this particular case) but it would be seriously ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two problems here.

If you turn on debugging output for the ProfilingATNSimulator, you will see that the large lookahead is required at the very first '(' of the partial input string `((select 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 1)`. AdaptivePredict() knows that we are trying to find an `expr`, but we need to decide among the various alts for the rule which to take. We need to read to the very end of the entire expression--to the matching ')'--in order to make that decision. Why?

AdaptivePredict() needs to find an 'IN' (or not) ***after the entire expression `((select 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 1)`*** to decide to take (or not) the 3rd alt `| expr 'IN' expr`.

Part of the solution here is to rewrite the 3rd alt as `| Atom 'IN' expr`, which restricts the use of 'IN' to be a single atom. This seems okay based on your one example input.

The other problem is the common prefix between the 1st and 2nd alts of expr. The solution is to merge the two alts together: `| '(' expr (',' expr)* ')'`.

The fixed grammar is:

```
grammar DBParser;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }
statement: select EOF;

select:
    'SELECT' expr (',' expr)*
    ('FROM' expr) ?
    ('WHERE' expr) ?
    ;

expr
    : '(' expr (',' expr)* ')'
    | Atom 'IN' expr          
    | '(' select ')'          
    | Atom                    
    ;

Atom:
    [a-z-]+ | [0-9]+ | '\'' Atom '\''
    ;

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

The fixed grammar has a max k of 2.

Note, I really don't understand why people like alt labeling. It clutters the grammar and forces a renaming of visitors and listeners methods. For this grammar, any alt can be determined by testing a few choice children. I removed all alt labeling accordingly.

Comment: thanks for this great answer. Two questions/comments with this: (1) yes it would require an `expr` not just an atom on the lhs, an example being `2+4 IN (4,6,8)`; (2) why do you suggest avoiding alt labeling? Here is an example I've been referencing a bit and is full of altNamings: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4#L2437.

Comment: I will have to think of an alternative set of rules for the IN operator. On labeling, I almost never use Antlr visitors or listeners anymore. But if I did, I can determine the alt by looking at the children of the node. Visitors are way too primitive to be of use to me. I use XPath2 to navigate around the tree. Visitors are to XPath2 as assembly language is to C#, Java, or some other programming language.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, what might be an example of how Visitors/Listeners are primitive compared to XPath? I've always found XPath a bit tricky (anything beyond basic XPath1.0).

Comment: Examples of XPath on parse trees: http://codinggorilla.com/blog/2020/06/30/direct-left-recursion-via-xpath.html. http://codinggorilla.com/blog/2022/08/21/useless-parentheses.html

Comment: wow that's really cool.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be very interested to see if anyone has a trick that will address that Max K.  If I'm just "being the compiler", I can't really identify whether the first paren is a tuple or a parenthesized expression without looking ahead in the token stream to the character after the first `)`.

Lookahead does have performance implications, there's no way around that.

That being said, this is something of a compulsive case, so you will have to be the judge as to how common that could be.  Given the ability to embed a complex `select` statement as a member (or members) of a tuple, it may be more common that one might guess.

IF you have the discretion to use another syntax for tuples (here I'm just picking `{` and `}` for testing sake):

```
expr
    : '(' expr ')'              # parenExpression
    | '{' expr (',' expr)+ '}'  # tupleLiteralExpression
    | expr 'IN' expr            # inExpression
    | '(' select ')'            # subSelectExpression
    | Atom                      # constantExpression
    ;
```

Then Max K drops to 2 because the `{` "gives away" the fact that it'll be a tuple.  As long as it's the same character as nested expressions, I don't see any way to avoid long lookahead to resolve the parse rule.

Comment: yea that's a good point. I was even thinking of putting the comma at the beginning of the tuple (added in by the generated statement, the user of course wouldn't add it in), but yea I think using some prefix separator like that is a good idea. Do you know of any other places in SQL where there's a potentially late-resolving ambiguity like the above?

Comment: I "get by" with SQL, so can say that I know of anything like that